# google chrome & maybe others weird layout issue

Tags: jquery, layout, safari, google-chrome

I am using a jquery plugin called masonry. 
In IE & firefox, the site works as it's supposed to. However, in google chrome, the layout elements get stacked on one another. If I click the menu items on the left, then the plugin reloads and the site looks like it's supposed to.

So, I think it must be a timing issue. Any thoughts on how to resolve?
http://jasondaydesign.com/masonry_demo/

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Chromium, I get the following errors:

`Unmatched </a> encountered.  Ignoring tag.
XML self-closing tag syntax used on <a>. The tag will not be closed.`

Check your HTML (use the w3c validator to be sure), and everything should work fine.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjasondaydesign.com%2Fmasonry_demo%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the errors, but the layout was still wonky. So I moved the call for the js to the bottom of the page, and this resolved the issue. I think in chrome, the elements were arranging prior to the content within them loading.

Thanks for the help!